# Is this a bug? (Collate + duplex printing = unexpected behaviour)

Tags: printing, bugs

Given the following facts:

- We have a document that consists of multiple pages
- We print multiple copies of it
- We print duplex (double-sided)
- We enable the option `collate`

Under several Linux distro's I get the following result:
First a stack of pages with page 1 on *both* sides. Then a stack with page 2 on *both* sides, &c.

I can not think of any situation in which this would be the desired behaviour. I would however like to see a stack of (page 1 + 2), and then a stack of (page 3 + 4), &c.

#### My questions:

- Do you recognize this behaviour?
- Do you also think this is a bug?
- If so, where should this be fixed?

I realize that this a bit open and vague, but all the people that I have spoken lately (IRL @ the university printer, and such) think this is strange behaviour. At first I decided to avoid `collate`, but lately I got so agitated that I wanted to attack this problem. However, I would first like to hear some of your opinions/answers.

Comment: Well, I have seen it happen on at least 4 different printers (mostly on non-personal sytems, so I cannot check the drivers). But it seems to be pretty broad (hence my first question).

Comment: You should fire a bug report instead of asking here

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the *collate* and *duplex* are getting blended... the program is sending all the page 1's, which the printer dutifully duplexes, then the page 2's and so forth.

I'd turn off the collate, let the printer duplex as it's supposed to.  If you want to collate... it doesn't make sense to duplex.

collate usually interpreted as 'all page 1's' in one output, then all page 2's, three's and so forth... so it's almost expected behavior to output as you described.

Comment: I know what collate does. But suppose a teacher has 2-page handouts for his lessons, and he has all his handouts in one file. Then I can imagine that it makes sense to collate + duplex print this. He would get one pile for each lesson, with nice double-sided handouts. So in some sense (for duplex) the expected behaviour would be to send all pages 1&2, , which the printer dutifully duplexes, then the page 3&4's and so forth.

Comment: It may just depend on how the developer wrote the code, either in the printer driver on the computer, or the firmware in the printer.  Just a quirk.